# Java gateway process exited before sending its port number Spark

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark

I am trying to install Spark in my Windows 10 with Anaconda, but I got an error when I try to runs pyspark in my JupyterNotebook. 
I am following the steps in this [tutorial](https://medium.com/@naomi.fridman/install-pyspark-to-run-on-jupyter-notebook-on-windows-4ec2009de21f). Then, I already download Java 8 and install, Spark 3.0.0, Hadoop 2.7.

I already set the paths for SPARK_HOME, JAVA_HOME, and include the '/bin' paths in the "PATH" environment.

```
C:\Users\mikes>java -version
java version "1.8.0_251"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_251-b08)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.251-b08, mixed mode)
```

In PowerShell of Anaconda pyspark it works.

```
(base) PS C:\Users\mikes> pyspark
Python 3.6.5 |Anaconda, Inc.| (default, Mar 29 2018, 13:32:41) [MSC v.1900 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
20/06/05 07:14:56 WARN NativeCodeLoader: Unable to load native-hadoop library for your platform... 
using builtin-java classes where applicable
Using Spark's default log4j profile: org/apache/spark/log4j-defaults.properties
Setting default log level to "WARN".
To adjust logging level use sc.setLogLevel(newLevel). For SparkR, use setLogLevel(newLevel).
Welcome to
    ____              __
   / __/__  ___ _____/ /__
 _ \ \/ _ \/ _ `/ __/  '_/
/__ / .__/\_,_/_/ /_/\_\   version 3.0.0-preview2
   /_/

Using Python version 3.6.5 (default, Mar 29 2018 13:32:41)
SparkSession available as 'spark'.
>>>
>>> nums = sc.parallelize([1,2,3,4])
>>> nums.map(lambda x: x*x).collect()
[1, 4, 9, 16]
>>>
```

Netx step is runs pyspark in my Jupyter Notebook.
I already install `findspark`
then, my code for start in:

```
import findspark
findspark.init('c:\spark\spark-3.0.0-preview2-bin-hadoop2.7')
#doesent work findspark.init() is necessary write the path.
findspark.find()
import pyspark
from pyspark import SparkContext, SparkConf
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession

conf = pyspark.SparkConf().setAppName('appName').setMaster('local')
sc = pyspark.SparkContext(conf=conf) #Here is the error
spark = SparkSession(sc)
```

The error that shows:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
Exception                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-6-c561ad39905c> in <module>()
      4 conf = pyspark.SparkConf().setAppName('appName').setMaster('local')
      5 sc = pyspark.SparkConf()
----> 6 sc = pyspark.SparkContext(conf=conf)
      7 spark = SparkSession(sc)

c:\spark\spark-3.0.0-preview2-bin-hadoop2.7\python\pyspark\context.py in __init__(self, master, appName, sparkHome, pyFiles, environment, batchSize, serializer, conf, gateway, jsc, profiler_cls)
    125                 " is not allowed as it is a security risk.")
    126 
--> 127         SparkContext._ensure_initialized(self, gateway=gateway, conf=conf)
    128         try:
    129             self._do_init(master, appName, sparkHome, pyFiles, environment, batchSize, serializer,

c:\spark\spark-3.0.0-preview2-bin-hadoop2.7\python\pyspark\context.py in _ensure_initialized(cls, instance, gateway, conf)
    317         with SparkContext._lock:
    318             if not SparkContext._gateway:
--> 319                 SparkContext._gateway = gateway or launch_gateway(conf)
    320                 SparkContext._jvm = SparkContext._gateway.jvm
    321 

c:\spark\spark-3.0.0-preview2-bin-hadoop2.7\python\pyspark\java_gateway.py in launch_gateway(conf, popen_kwargs)
    103 
    104             if not os.path.isfile(conn_info_file):
--> 105                 raise Exception("Java gateway process exited before sending its port number")
    106 
    107             with open(conn_info_file, "rb") as info:

Exception: Java gateway process exited before sending its port number
```

I saw another question similar to this one, but maybe the situation is another, because I already tried those solutions, as:

-Set another party for `PYSPARK_SUBMIT_ARGS`, but I do not know if I a doing wrong.

```
os.environ['PYSPARK_SUBMIT_ARGS']= "--master spark://localhost:8888"
```

the other solutions are: 
- Set path for `JAVA_HOME, SPARK_HOME` (already did it)
- Install Java 8 (not 10)

I already spend some hours trying, even a reinstall Anaconda because I delete an environment.

Answer (score 2):

After one week looking for different ways to solve the exception showed, finally I found [another tutorial](https://changhsinlee.com/install-pyspark-windows-jupyter/), but this solved my question, the answer is Anaconda is the problem, the same variables and paths are the same. Then I install notebook python directly in my Windows (without Anaconda), now the issue was solved.

Answer (score 0):

I agree. For me also worked, in the jyputer notebook, to do !conda install pyspark (while before I had only done !pip install ... )